# how can we send data from action handler to popuppresenter with out using RPC machanisim

Tags: gwtp

In my project.i have below requirement.
 we have to send some request to ATM.
so before sending response Atm will send some notifications.
As per requirement we have to listen the notifications and some how we need to send these content of this Notification tag to presenter.

for example

we are sending request to ATM---Rq1
then it sends some notifications like N1--it is a xml so for example value tag value is "some text".so this we need to send to presenter.if again we receive
N1 then needs to send the value tag value to presenter.so all these should send to presenter immediately.
once we receive response from ATM we can send the response data by using RPC.

The main motive is if we receive notification at 10:00 AM then we should send value tag value to the presenter.then next notification if we receive at 10:01 that value tag also we need to update to presenter.

So kindly advise us..if my question is not clear kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, an RPC call will only return once. And a server cannot directly communicate to a browser like the browser can to a server.

You might want to implement an asynchronous polling system. Essentially, your call your main RPC service, call it `bigMethod()`. After you call it, you immediately and asynchronously begin calling a polling method. just call it `poll()`.

Every second or two, (or however long you think), it runs out to the ATM to check if there's a message. Once `bigMethod()` finishes you stop polling.

The downside is that this solution will require some tweaking of the back end code to handle it.

Comment: HI Ben ..
Thank you so much for your briefly explanation.I am sorry may be i have not properly explain my concern ...

My requirement is how can we fire an event from server side(Action handler) to presenter in GWTP.I know we can use RPC calls but in my project before RPC call response i need to fire events from server side to presenter with string value.

Comment: I edited my answer to respond to your actual question. Sorry about the confusion. :)

Comment: Can u Kindly explain me how can we use poll() clearly.If possible can u pls provide some sample code for this.